# Delphi 2006 Application messing up the GUI on Windows 7

Tags: delphi, user-interface, windows-vista, compatibility, delphi-2006

I've been searching the Internet for a solution. Also here on Stackoverflow. But I haven't had any luck so far.

We're having a problem with a Delphi 2006 application running on Windows 7. Some ComboBoxes are not shown. The exactly same application runs fine on Windows XP.

I been trying to locate any patches. Do any one of you know any links or hack to make to GUI look as it should when running a Delphi 2006 application on Vista/Windows 7?

I've found this link: http://www.theabsolute.net/sware/delphivista.html. But it doesn't solve my problems.

Any help are welcome.

/Brian

Answer (score 0):

This may be one of a couple of issues; you haven't given much in the way of details. "Some comboboxes are not shown" doesn't help a lot.

The things I've run across that caused these kinds of problems:

- Large fonts when the app was designed with normal fonts
- Custom DPI settings (eg., 120 DPI instead of the "standard" 96 DPI)

EDIT after Brian's comment:

That's really strange. I've never seen visual differences between apps compiled in the IDE and command-line.

The only thing I can think of is that the command-line version might have some compiler defines that are affecting the comboboxes (unlikely), or the command-line version is seeing a different version of the .pas and .dfm and that version doesn't have the comboboxes on the form.

You might try making sure that there is only a single copy of the affected .dfm and .pas files on the build machine, and then verify they have the right appearance before compilation. (Use Windows search to check for multiple copies of the source files, and search the entire system just to make sure.)

I've never had this issue with visual controls, but have had it with source changes that didn't seem to take effect, or breakpoints that didn't break because the compiler was seeing a different version of the file than I was... I don't know if that's the case here, but it might be worth checking.

Comment: Hi Ken.

Thanks for your feedback. 

I don't know how else I can describe the problem? My lack of information is caused by my knowledge about the problem :o)

I got a bit closer to the source of the problem. It turns of that an application compiled with the IDE works fine on Windows 7. But the same application compiled using our build tool fails. We're using the commandline compiler DCC to compiler our applicationer. We've tried to use DCC manually (without the buildtool) and it causes the same problem with the disapeared comboboxes.

That's as far we come so far with this problem.

/Brian